# Using Func to capture a Class Property

Tags: c#, lambda, closures, graph-algorithm, func

I am working on implementing a graph class. In class I learned that the breadth-first and depth-first traversals are the same algorithms except to store the traversing nodes a queue and stack is used respectively. So I put all my logic into a Traversal() method which is called by DepthFirstSearch() which passes in a stack as the ADT.

```
public void DepthFirstSearch(GraphNode<T> root)
{
    Stack<GraphNode<T>> s = new Stack<GraphNode<T>>();

    Action<GraphNode<T>> insert = s.Push;
    Func<GraphNode<T>> retrieve = s.Pop;
    //Func<int> stackCount = s.Count; Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to System.Func<int>' error
    Func<int> stackCount = () => s.Count;

    Traversal(root, insert, retrieve, stackCount);
}
```

I am assuming that I cannot pass s.Count into a delegate because it is a class property? So to get around it I used a lambda to closure around that property. But can anyone explain why I need lambda for s.Count but not for s.Pop or s.Push? Thanks.

Comment: Porbably because Push and Pop are methods, count is a property, unless you want the Linq Count() extension method - I'm assuming that Stack has a count property and that is what's happening

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549151.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is because [`Stack<T>.Push`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6335ax0f.aspx) and [`Stack<T>.Pop`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9say334k.aspx) are *already* functions that are compatible with the type of delegate ([`Func<TResult>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534960.aspx) and [`Action<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/018hxwa8.aspx), where `TResult` and `T` match the generic type parameter of your [`Stack<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx)—in your case, `GraphNode<T>`) to which you're trying to assign the methods. If they weren't compatible, you would need to use a lambda function or some other sort of wrapper delegate to assign the method to your delegate variable.

While a class property *technically* consists of a getter and a setter method, in C#, those details are abstracted away, requiring you to wrap a class property in a lambda function. Also, per Servy's comments below, the compiler wouldn't be able to easily determine whether you're trying to assign the getter or the setter to the delegate variable.

Comment: Also, you may be over abstracting, unless this is just a learning exercise.  (Those are valuable, I don't discount them!) In practice your code might be more clear and more maintainable with directly coded DepthFirst and BreadthFirst traversals.  Too many levels of indirection and abstraction can making coming back to your code after six weeks or six years a nightmare.   Use abstraction when it really buys you something.   The DRY thing should be taken in moderation, like most things.

Comment: And if you are abstracting... then you should abstract the "stack" creation into a factory method, that returns the complete object, wrapped with the API you need! :-)

Comment: `"The reason is because Stack.Push and Stack.Pop are already functions"` whose signatures match the delegates you're assigning them to.  That's a key point you excluded.  If the signatures didn't match *exactly* you'd need to use a lambda (or something else) to assign those methods to those delegates.  Oh, and another reason you couldn't assign the property directly is that the compiler wouldn't know if you're trying to assign the `get` or the `set` method, because the property represents both.  (Technically `Count` only has a getter, but to cover the general case...)

Comment: Servy, you are absolutely correct. I've updated my answer to be more specific.